# React-Select клонирование

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select

При клонировании div:

```
const duplicate = () => {
    let multiRow = document.getElementById("rowMultiSend");
    let clone = multiRow.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById("formMultiSend").appendChild(clone);
};
```

Внутри `rowMultiSend` находится компонента `react-select`

Когда я нажимаю кнопку добавления нового `multiRow` не работает последующие `react-select` компоненты, они как-будто заморожены, с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: С тем, что вы клонируете HTML элементы, а не react компоненты.

Comment: То есть мне просто нужно создать компоненту, внутри которой будет весь этот div в котором будет компонента react-select, верно?

Comment: Не понимаю вашего вопроса. React, на основе react компонентов создает vitrual-dom, который в свою очередь рендерит в html-dom. Вы же пытаетесь изменив html-dom создать react компонент, так это не работает. Если вам нужно создать еще 1 react компонент, то и создавать вам его нужно, как react-комонент. Через манипуляции с html-dom у вас это не получится.

Comment: Здесь почитайте https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html

Comment: Спасибо, я понял свою ошибку.

Comment: Если вам требуется напрямую клонировать компоненты, то у вас проблемы с архитектурой. Если вам требуется логика, при которой по какому-либо событию происходит добавление новых блоков, то реализовывайте рендер этих блоков, скажем, через специально отведенный массив объектов в стейте и `map()`, а в обработчике этого события ставьте изменения - но не ДОМа, а того самого массива в стейте. Тогда все будет благоразумно